# How to find system of equations from solution space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I have to find homogeneous system of linear equations whose solution space is: V = span((1,-2,4,3),(1,-1,6,4),(3,-8,8,3)).
First I found vectors were linearly dependent, so I discarded the third vector to form a new base. Next I figured system will have 2 free variables and if we would use gauss-jordan elimination on matrix of a system we would get this:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & * & *\\
        0 & 1 & * & * \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now I don't know how to find *'s or if I am on a right path. Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the 3 vectors are linearly independent. For example, it is not hard to check that $$\left|\begin{array}{cccc}1 & -2 & 4 & 3 \\ 1 & -1 & 6 & 4 \\ 3 & -8 & 8 & 3 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right|=-32\ne0$$ So we expect there will be just one equation. Suppose it is that the vector $(w,x,y,z)$ must satisfy $aw+bx+cy+dz=0$. Then we know that $a,b,c,d$ must satisfy:

(1) $a-2b+4c+3d=0$, (2) $a-b+6c+4d=0$, (3) $3a-8b+8c+3d=0$

Taking (2)-(1), we get $b+2c+d=0$, and taking 2(2)-(1), we get $a+8c+5d=0$. Substituting in (3) gives $d=0$. So the only possible equation is essentially $8w+2x-y=0$. It is easy to check that the three given points all satisfy it and hence all linear combinations of those points will also satisfy it.

Comment: Oh I am very sorry, third vector is actually (3,-8,8,7). But I think I understand the principle now! thanks.

Comment: @almagest, I'm working on a similar problem, and I have a few questions. First, why should we expect just one equation? Second, I follow up until $8w + 2x - y = 0$; where does that come from?

Comment: @dmk I suspect I am on a different time zone (now 6:12am in London UK) :) Unfortunately I am running late for mass, so I will probably make a stupid mistake, but having got $d=0$, that gives us (putting that into the two equations we just derived) $b+2c=0,a+8c=0$. In other words, it gives us $a,b$ in terms of $c$. So we have: $a=-8c,b=-2c,c=c,d=0$. Remember these are the coefficients of $aw+bx+cy+dz=0$, so that equation must be $-8cw-2cx+cy=0$. Since $c$ is a common factor it does not matter what its value is, provided it is non-zero. I put it as $-1$ giving $8w+2x-y=0$. Does that help?

Comment: It helped me! Thanks @almagest!